# Experiencing explainable issues using Permission Request in Xamarin Forms on Android 10

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-permissions

This issue I am currently experiencing only appears to be apparent on Android 10, older versions of Android work perfectly fine. I've tested this on a physical and emulated devices and I get the same results.

My app requests the user for access to the CAMERA and of course this will prompt a permission request, this works perfect. My default stance was when I called for the camera using the Zxing Barcode Scanner library that I would let that make the request. Getting to this page had a series of loading screens and I experienced a bizarre moment, when sending the request several loading screens re-appear and the app becomes unusable, not a clue why; restarting the app resolves this.

I decided to take on the approach of using runtime permission request instead, so when the app launches it will check and make a request then and there; after the splash screen. Again, works fine but another weird experience. This approach lands me on a blank screen, I've figured out why I just don't know why.

This is the code I now have to make the request, which works.

```
String[] requiredPermissions = new String[] {
    Manifest.Permission.Camera
};

RequestPermissions(requiredPermissions, 1);

LoadApplication(new App());
```

User launches the app, loads Splashscreen, then loads MainActivity, then (on first use) pops up and requests access to the camera, regardless of how the user responds my app stops working as I expect it to; no crashes, freezing, etc. Just sits on a blank page. I'm not sure if my approach is the best, or anyone can suggest a better approach, but below will hopefully visual what I have.

When MainActivity calls `LoadApplication(new App());` which calls my App.xaml.cs I have this as my constructor

```
public App() {
    MainPage = new ContentPage();
}

protected ovverride OnStart() {
    // Code here determines which page to load
}
```

Both methods are called, I can breakpoint and hit in both methods. My expectations are that in `OnStart()` which is hit after the constructor, that what ever page I set as `MainPage` here, should be what I see. Instead, despite stepping through the code my `MainPage` remains `new ContentPage()`.

Now, if I removed `RequestePermissions(requiredPermissions, 1)` from MainActivity - everything works as it once did. However, put it back and things stop working again.

Does anyone understand and can explain why I may be experiencing this blank screen scenario?

Why would my app load my selected page in `OnStart()` correctly if I don't use `RequestePermissions(requiredPermissions, 1)` but chooses not to, when I do use the Request method.

Any and all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using the Permissions plugin?  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: I've just downloaded and installed this NuGet... It surprisingly worked straight off the bat, my entire problem has just vanished. Thank you! That said though, without the use of this NuGet, do you have any idea why my app may have being behaving as it is?